# Why is this value downcast (static_cast to object type) allowed in C++20?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, downcast, static-cast

To my surprise, gcc 11.2 [accepts this code](https://cxx20.godbolt.org/z/e7K86ojo8), but only in C++20 mode:

```
struct Base {};
struct Derived : Base { int i; };
int f(Base& b) { return static_cast<Derived>(b).i; }
//                                  ^~~~~~~ oops, forgot the `&`
```

Likewise, MSVC 19.29 accepts it in C++20 mode and rejects it in C++17 mode, but clang rejects it even in C++20 mode.

Looking at the assembler output, `f` always returns `0`, so it's ignoring the actual data of any potential `Derived` passed to `f`.

Is this UB, or is it legal in C++20, and if so, why?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is legal in C++20.

[[expr.static.cast]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.static.cast#4.sentence-1):

> An expression `E` can be explicitly converted to a type `T` [...] if `T` is an aggregate type ([dcl.init.aggr]) having a first element `x` and there is an implicit conversion sequence from `E` to the type of `x`.

[[dcl.init.aggr]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init.aggr#2):

> The *elements* of an aggregate are: [...] for a class, the direct base classes in declaration order, followed by the direct non-static data members ([class.mem]) that are not members of an anonymous union, in declaration order.

So `Derived` is an aggregate whose first element is `Base`, and since C++20, it is permitted to create an aggregate from its first element.

This feature is introduced in [P1975R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1975r0.html) "Fixing the wording of parenthesized aggregate-initialization".

Comment: This is one of the most counter-intuitive pieces of code I've seen in C++20. Aggregates continue being an unpredictable mess.

Comment: So I can write `int arr[2] = {1,2} ; cout << (int)arr;` and it will print 1?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica That would print a pointer. It's the other way around, `static_cast<int[2]>(42)` is now legal it seems.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oh. I see, yes. Basically, you can convert an element to an aggregate of elements. In a way, they always were arrays of length 1, conceptually.